# Using labelFormatting in ngx-chart pie

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

The pie chart in ngx-chart shows only the name of the data record as the label, but I want to also display its value in the label. I saw that it should be possible to change the label format with `labelFormatting`, but there is no example provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to your chartData from within your labelFormatting method on the series property. You can achieve it with following code:

```
  // your chartData maybe like this
  chartData = [
    { name: "Prod 1", value: 22 },
    { name: "Prod 2", value: 11 },
    { name: "Prod 3", value: 33 }
  ];
  

  labelFormatting(name) { // this name will contain the name you defined in chartData[]
    let self: any = this; // this "this" will refer to the chart component (pun intented :))

    let data = self.series.filter(x => x.name == name); // chartData will be present in
                                                        // series along with the label

    if(data.length > 0) {
      return `${data[0].name}: ${data[0].value}`;
    } else {
      return name;
    }
  }
```

HTML will be like this:

```
    <ngx-charts-pie-chart 
        [results]="chartData"
        [legend]="false"
        [view]="[275,250]"
        [animations]="true"
        [labels]="true"
        [labelFormatting]="labelFormatting">
     </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Note: I am using ngx-charts version 16.0.0

Comment: Where is the `html code`?

Comment: Added the html, please check.

Comment: When testing the above, the callback doesn't get triggered unfortunately 

Answer (score 1):

You can format the label if you set a function to the `labelFormatting` input of the chart component as shown below:

```
 <ngx-charts-pie-chart
    [results]="yourData"
    [labelFormatting]="myLabelFormatter"   
  ></ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

The ngx chart component calls the linked function with each label value as a argument. In the formatting function you can manipulate the label value and must return a value that is then placed as label text, see example formatting function that adds a percentage symbol to the original label text:

```
public myLabelFormatter(ev) {
   return ev + '%';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript **Array.prototype.find()** worked for me:

```js
/* 
import { SingleSeries } from @swimlane/ngc-charts/lib/models/chart-data.model

export interface SingleSeries extends Array<DataItem> {}

export interface DataItem {
    name: StringOrNumberOrDate;
    value: number;
    extra?: any;
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
    label?: string;
}
*/

var chartData: SingleSeries = 
  [
    { name: 'First', value: 10 },
    { name: 'Second', value: 50 },
    { name: 'Third', value: 30 },
    { name: 'Fourth', value: 10 }
  ]

function labelFormat = (labelName) => {
    //Find the data by labelName from chartData 
    const dataPoint = this.chartData.find(x => x.name === labelName);
    
    //returns 10% for 'First' label, 50% for 'Second' label and so on.
    return `${dataPoint.value}%`;
}
```

```html
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
  [results]="chartData"
  [labels]="true"
  [labelFormatting]="labelFormat">
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Comment: This, Array.prototype.find(), has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score -2):

Is an example on how to implement [labelFormatting]="....." functionality for pie-chart.
I tried implementing (below) on pie-chart:

```
   <ngx-charts-pie-chart
        [results]="chartData"
        [view]="view"
        [labelFormatting]="setLabelFormatting"   
      ></ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

where:

```
  setLabelFormatting(c): string {
    return `${c.label}<br/><span class="custom-label-text">${c.value}</span>`;
  }
```

and:

```
.custom-label-text {
  background-color: #00b400;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This did not work. It just printed the literal text in the label

Comment: @Christine probably this depends on the kind of chart. I personally am trying to work out solution for better formatted pie chart labels, but as per most recent documentation these are not supporting multi lines. Actually the labels are plain text escaping any html tag overall. Thus, for me at least, I confirm "This did not work"